# Compression response filter fails on breeze.js Metadata call

Tags: filter, metadata, action, gzip, breeze

I have an http module where I'm adding a response filter below for compression.  This works for all API calls except for 1, the call to MetaData.  If I remove the  [BreezeController] decoration it works fine.  I think it has to do with action filter attribute that converts the string return type into an HttpResponse return type with string content.

The error I'm getting is " Exception message: The stream state of the underlying compression routine is inconsistent."

I've done some testing where a method thats defined to return an HttpResponse  works fine.  So I think its the scenario where the method is defined to return string, and then the action filter changes it to HttpResponse at runtime.

Any ideas how I can get this to work?

Here's the response filter being added in BeginRequest:

```
        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;


        // Check the header to see if it can accept compressed output
        string encodings = app.Request.Headers.Get("Accept-Encoding");

        if (encodings == null)
            return;

        Stream s = app.Response.Filter;
        encodings = encodings.ToLower();

        if (encodings.Contains("gzip"))
        {
                app.Response.Filter = new GZipStream(s, CompressionMode.Compress);
                app.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know the specifics of what you're doing but I know that the `[BreezeController]` attribute strips out filters and adds back just the ones that breeze wants.

One approach might be to define a separate controller  (`ModelMetadataController`) that only serves the metadata. This controller doesn't have the `[BreezeController]` attribute; it's a plain old Web API controller.

Then you create a "Breeze controller" (`ModelController`) with all of the usual methods except the `Metadata` method.

You call the metadata controller from the client during app launch via `MetadataStore.fetchMetadata` just to get metadata.

Once you have populated a `metadataStore` in this fashion, you use it in your `EntityManager` which sends query and save requests to the "real" Web API data controller.

The client code might look something like this:

```
var ds = new breeze.DataService({
    serviceName: 'breeze/Model'   // the breeze query & save controller
});

var ms = new MetadataStore({
    namingConvention: breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase, // assuming that's what you want
});
ms.addDataService(ds); // associate the metadata-to-come with the "real" dataService

var manager = new breeze.EntityManager({
    dataService:   ds,
    metadataStore: ms
});

// the fun bit: fetch the metadata from a different controller
var promise = ms.fetchMetadata('breeze/ModelMetadata')  // the metadata-only controller!
return promise; // wait on it appropriately
```